# How to Make White Transparent in a Shader

Tags: texturing, shaders

(Eevee) So I have 2 textures hooked up to a color ramp, but I want to combine them in such a way that the colors on either isn't desaturated. I tried a whole heap of blend modes, this seems like a really basic maneuver in shading but I just could not findanything on this except for stuff that only works in cycles.

**Neanderthal node setup**
[image: neanderthal node setup]

**Node output**
[image: Node output]

**What I want the node to spew out**
[image: What I want the node to spew out]

Thanks to any legend who points me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, here it's one of them:

[image]

In your color ramps you need to replace the white color with a transparent one (just set the *Alpha* value to 0). That way you can have a white background and add the colors on top by using the *Alpha* output of the color ramps.

An alternative way could be to use the black color instead of the alpha and choose *Screen* or *Add* as blend modes